# How to set up a feedback form on the php to the letters you do not end up in spam?

Tags: php, html, email, gmail, email-client

It seems all you need is there, but the messages are still not sent. Most likely, they do not reach because of the anti-spam.

How can I fix the problem?

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
            <strong>Your name:</strong><br />
            <input maxlength="30" type="text" name="name" />
            <br />
            <strong>Your Email for response:</strong><br />
            <input maxlength="30" type="text" name="email" />
            <br />
            <strong>Yuur massage</strong><br />
            <textarea rows="7" cols="50" name="mess"></textarea>
            <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
            </p>
            </form>



       <?php
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name'];}
    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email'];}
    if (isset($_POST['mess'])) {$mess = $_POST['mess'];}

    $to = "engenes511@gmail.com"; 
    $headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=windows-1251\r\nFrom: <e9228098808@yandex.ru>";
    $subject = "Message from your site";
    $message = "Sender name: $name \nE-mail: $email \nMassage: $mess";
    $send = mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    if ($send == 'true')
    {
    echo "<b>Thank you for sending your message!<p>";
    echo "<a href='feedback.html'>Click to return</a>";
    }
    else 
    {
    echo "<p><b>Error. Message not sent!";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Give me a link to the answer?

Comment: `if ($send == 'true')` that checks against a string btw. Look at the manual on boolean `true|false` http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php so that will never evaluate to `true`.